# Using timer in Windows Mobile during standby

Tags: events, windows-mobile, timer

I want to use a timer in a windows mobile app. Of course, this is not the problem.

The problem: the timer needs to be called even during standby and sleep mode.

Simply switching off the sleep mode is not really an option, since the app needs to comply to windows marketplace for mobiles requirements, and regarding to requirement 5.2 a marketplace app "shall not modify power management options".

Is there a system timer, which could be used to get an event called (like CeSetUserNotificationEx can be used to get an app started)?
Or how would I create a persistent timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CeRunAppAtTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931253.aspx) can be used to set a named system event (not just to run an app).  If the device is in sleep mode when that time arrives, it will wake.

Comment: In the headerfile notify.h, where CeRunAppAtTime is defined, it says: "Obsolete; provided to maintain compatibility only".

Seems that CeSetUserNotificationEx is the new CeRunAppAtTime now, but still it might be the right function to have a look into, thanks!